# Games where $\omega(G) < \omega^*(G) < \omega^{ns}(G) < 1$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, it.information-theory, gt.game-theory, quantum-information

A two player game $G = (I,O,V,p)$ is such that, if two non-communicating players Alice and Bob are given questions $(x,y)\in I^2$ drawn from the probability distribution $p$, they are supposed to produce two answers $(a,b) \in O^2$ such that $V(x,y,a,b) = 1$ - in which case they are said to *win* the game $G$. The maximum probability that Alice and Bob can win the game $G$, over the randomness of the inputs and their strategies, is called the *value* of the game. The value of the game can change depending on the resources allowed: if Alice and Bob are purely classical players, then the classical value is denoted $\omega(G)$. If Alice and Bob can share quantum entanglement and employ quantum strategies, they can achieve a quantum value $\omega^*(G)$. If Alice and Bob can share general *no-signalling* strategies, they can achieve a no-signalling value $\omega^{ns}(G)$. It is known that $\omega(G) \leq \omega^*(G) \leq \omega^{ns}(G) \leq 1$. Are there games for which all three inequalities are strict?

For example, the famed CHSH game is an example of which *two* of the inequalities are strict: $\omega(G) < \omega^*(G) < \omega^{ns}(G)$, but $\omega^{ns}(G) = 1$.

Comment: Consider the following game: flip a coin (which is visible to both players). If the coin is heads, play the CHSH game. If the coin is tails, play a game where $\omega^{ns} < 1$.